# Error when building my electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, fs, pouchdb

I'm stuck with a problem when building my Node JS/electron app with **electron-builder**. It works perfectly when running `npm start`. But, when I execute the command `build -w` (for windows) it fails with [this log](https://crerensak.com/ARENA/loggy).

Here is my JSON file:

```
{
  "name": "Munshiiii",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is a short Description of the project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "dist": "build -w"
  },
  "author": "Hicham Dbiza",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "1.7.8",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^1.4.13"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "asar": "^0.13.0",
    "cradle": "^0.7.1",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "git": "^0.1.5",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jsdom": "^11.3.0",
    "loke-ipc": "^1.0.5",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.33",
    "node-couchdb": "^1.2.0",
    "pouchdb": "^6.3.4",
    "pouchdb-replication-stream": "^1.2.9",
    "scanner.js": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "build":{
    "appId": "com.hicham.dbiza.faizan",
    "win":{
        "target": "nsis",
        "icon": "build/Munshiiii.ico"
    }
  }
}
```

for this project Im using:

- fs
- pouchdb
- electron
- jquery
- ....

I already used electron-packager and it works almost fine with one problem: [See this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3J9h8.jpg), which means all links inside the js files (e.g:  fs.readFileSync('./assets/state','utf8')) won't work.
I have also added some native js click and keypress listeners... could that be a problem?

My electron version is 1.7.8.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: What your electron version? please write in your question

Comment: My electron version is  1.7.8

Comment: what is electron builder version.did you tried to use recent electron . try to change "dist": "build -w" to    "dist": "build --win"

Comment: done and still same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed `electron-builder`? You don't have it in your package.json. Then I would propose to use the `electron-builder` command, as [recommended by the authors](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/#quick-setup-guide).

Run `npm install electron-builder --save-dev` and change your `dist` command to run just `electron-builder`. Since electron-builder per default build for the current running OS, it's not necessary to send the `-w` flag. If you still experience problems, try to set the following env variable to get a [better stack trace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-builder#debug):

```
DEBUG=electron-builder,electron-builder:*
```

*Edit after getting more information from the comments:*
According to [this issue at GitHub](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/997) your first issue seemed to be caused by permission errors, and was solved with running as administrator.

From [electron-builders README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-builder#installation):

```
Yarn is strongly recommended instead of npm.

yarn add electron-builder --dev
```

Try to remove your `node_modules` folder and run

```
npm install yarn -g && yarn && yarn pack
```

Comment: I did all what you said electron-builder and manual installation and still got errors,  here is my last log using (electron builder) : [link](https://crerensak.com/ARENA/logyy2)
My new package.json : [link](https://crerensak.com/ARENA/packyy)

Comment: Did you run the `node_modules\.bin\electron-builder` command? Can you try to run the command as administrator as proposed at [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/997)?

Comment: It's hard to read the log in that picture, but it seems to be another error?

Comment: Okey. It seems to be a problem with the leveldown package. Do you receive any error when you just run `npm install`?

Comment: got these lines :  [link](https://crerensak.com/ARENA/npm%20install.JPG)

Comment: [Here is the link to my source code project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3hSl1V90IC9dUNOTGE0NFZVV0k/view?usp=sharing), I appreciate your help!

Comment: the file inside that link does not contain electron builder, you'll have to install it first, Again thanks

Comment: Okey. `npm install` seems to be okay. electron-builder runs best with `yarn instead of `npm`. Can you try to run `npm install yarn -g` and then run `yarn && yarn pack`?

Comment: And ensure that you run `yarn pack` as admin

Comment: Okey. And you removed node_modules before you did it? It looks like your problem with electron-builder is solved, and the one you're experiencing now is related to leveldown. You should checkout leveldown issues at GitHub, eg https://github.com/Level/leveldown/issues/277

Answer (score 0):

First I installed electron-builder with following line

```
npm install -g electron-builder
```

then I created a build folder in the root of my project, containing the .ico file with the app logo. then I wrote following parts in my package.json

```
"build": {
"appId": "your.app.id",
"productName": "Your final product name"
}
```

and

```
"scripts": {
"start": "electron .",
"pack": "build --dir"
}
```

That was everything I needed. I opend my root folder in the terminal and executed

```
build -w
```

That created an folder called dist, with an unpacked version of my app plus an installer for the app.

Comment: and maybe try "electron": "^1.7.9" in your package.json ... maybe that solves some problems^^

Answer (score 0):

**Yarn is strongly recommended instead of npm.**

```
yarn add electron-builder --dev
```

**if you are using Npm**
do just simple steps terminal:

1 `npm install yarn -g`  
2 `yarn`  
3 `yarn pack`

*[Read this Blog (reactJS in electronApp with .exe file)](https://medium.com/@devesu/how-to-build-a-react-based-electron-app-d0f27413f17f)*